# Problem adding charts (JFreeChart) to Pdf (iText)

Tags: java

When I add 1 chart to the document there is no problem

When I add the second chart I get this error ...

Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.IllegalPdfSyntaxException: Unbalanced save/restore state operators.

```
chart1 = SpecialJFreeChartBuilder.createChart1(
                "Site and Number of Requests ", results);

        document.newPage();

        PdfContentByte Add_Chart_Content = writer.getDirectContent();
        PdfTemplate template_Chart_Holder = Add_Chart_Content
                .createTemplate(width, height);
        Graphics2D Graphics_Chart = template_Chart_Holder.createGraphics(
                width, height, new DefaultFontMapper());
        Rectangle2D Chart_Region = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 540, 380);
        chart1.draw(Graphics_Chart, Chart_Region);
        Graphics_Chart.dispose();
        Add_Chart_Content.addTemplate(template_Chart_Holder, 0, 0);

        chart2 = SpecialJFreeChartBuilder.createChart2(
                "Site and totalAmount ", results);

        document.newPage();

        PdfContentByte Add_Chart_Content1 = writer.getDirectContent();
        PdfTemplate template_Chart_Holder1 = Add_Chart_Content1
                .createTemplate(width, height);
        Graphics2D Graphics_Chart1 = template_Chart_Holder1.createGraphics(
                width, height, new DefaultFontMapper());
        Rectangle2D Chart_Region1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 540, 380);
        chart2.draw(Graphics_Chart1, Chart_Region1);
        Graphics_Chart.dispose();
        Add_Chart_Content.addTemplate(template_Chart_Holder1, 0, 0);
```

....
                document.close();

Can anyone help me ....

Comment: Solved the issue ...

Graphics_Chart.dispose(); 

must be :

Graphics_Chart1.dispose(); 
Graphics_Chart2.dispose();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue ... Graphics_Chart.dispose(); must be : Graphics_Chart1.dispose(); Graphics_Chart2.dispose();